# Using decision trees to maximise continuous variable like profit

Tags: r, optimization, decision-tree, party

I have a dataset with profit as the target variable and about 100 different predictor variables (some binary, some continous and some character).

Is there a decision tree package in R that can be used that will give buckets (or end nodes) where profit is maximised (and preferably >0)?

Currently i have been using ctree from partykit package. The trees that are split invariably give good splits on the predictor variables, but the end-nodes invariably result in negative profit.

I am also having difficulty understanding the results at node end. These tend to be 'N=' and 'Error='. Is there some way to get 'profit=' instead so you can see what the best end node is?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simple things first: Understanding the printed results in each terminal node. Consider the following simple (and not particularly useful) `ctree` that models how the stopping `dist`ance of `cars` depends on their `speed`:

```
library("partykit")
ctree(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
## 
## Model formula:
## dist ~ speed
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] speed <= 17
## |   |   [3] speed <= 12: 18.200 (n = 15, err = 1176.4)
## |   |   [4] speed > 12: 39.750 (n = 16, err = 3535.0)
## |   [5] speed > 17: 65.263 (n = 19, err = 9015.7)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    2
## Number of terminal nodes: 3
```

This means for example that in node 5 there are `19` observations with `speed > 17` whose average stopping `dist`ance was `65.263` corresponding to an `err`or sum of squares of `9015.7`.

Thus, the mean of the target variable is given first (before the `n` and `err`) and is what you will be most interested in. To maximize the target variable you can then choose the terminal node with the highest predicted mean.

Finally, I wouldn't know of a tree method that is dedicated to profit maximization directly. The standard tree methods try to find terminal nodes that are homogenous in a certain way. (here with approximately constant average target value).

Comment: Ideally, I want a scenario where, when a particular variable of say, 5 attributes, is split. The decision tree sums up the profit in each permutation and splits the variable into two buckets where the difference in the summed profit is greatest. Is there any function that does this?

Comment: And then loops through each variable to find the variable with the greatest profit differentiation.This would then become node1...

Comment: This would need to be formulated more precisely for a reliable answer. It may be that standard regression trees are very close to what you want to do - but it might also be that it is very different. At the moment I'm not sure.

Comment: Here is some example data with profit being the dependent variable: